Laravel10 + VueJS3 Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded
Вообщем пару дней назад создал приложение на laravel10 + vuejs3. Сегодня написал апишку авторизации покидал запросы всё работает. После установил расширение для использования jwt, переписал авторизацию на такую:
public function login(LoginRequest $request): JsonResponse
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    $token = Auth::attempt($credentials);
    if ($token === false) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => 'Unauthorized',
        ], 401);
    }

    $user = Auth::user();
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'user' => $user,
        'authorisation' => [
            'token' => $token,
            'type' => 'bearer',
        ]
    ]);
}

И ответы начали валиться с 500 ошибкой
"Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"
Сама ошибка указывает сюда
file:"D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\my_project\\testLara\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse.php"
line: 88

Может кто знает как это поправить ??

Видимо в данных вашего ответа затесались символы не из UTF-8 кодировки. Проверяйте и делайте их конвертацию через mb_convert_encoding.

Оказывается проблема была совсем в другом. После того как я накатил плагин, он мне чутка изменил env, точнее просто дописал туда парочку строк, но и не только у меня слетели подключения к бд, поэтому валились данные ошибки, если конкретно он изменил только DB_HOST и DB_PASSWORD, все остальное как было несчитая еще 2 добавленных строк для jwt.

судя по ошибки он не может переварить массив, как совет просто деббагером проверь
[
    'status' => 'success',
    'user' => $user,
    'authorisation' => [
        'token' => $token,
        'type' => 'bearer',
    ]
]

Но, как я вижу скорее всего проблема в $user переменной, попробуй явно указать $user->toArray() или json, для теста можешь просто взять name из модели, например Auth::user()->name или удали строку с user
Должно помочь
